# Cannot access module from directive template, Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, directive

I’m trying to make a wrapper component for `ngAudio` the wrapper itself would be the player with controls - and would interact with ngAudio’s functions. I’m having some scope issues with it, I can inject it into the component’s controller and access `ngAudio` there, but I cannot access it from the scope of the template. I’ve tried setting `ngAudio` into scope using things like `$scope.ngAudio = ngAudio;` to no avail - if anyone has any ideas it would be awesome. I believe it will need some kind of two way binding? Or someway to generally access the ngAudio module from the directive level.

Code:

component:

```
.component('player', {
  // isolated scope binding
  bindings: {
    genre: '=',
    track: '=',
    ngAudio: '<'
  },

  templateUrl : '/templates/player-directive-template.html',

  // The controller that handles our component logic
  controller : function($scope, ngAudio) {

    //tried:
    //$scope.ngAudio = ngAudio;
    ngAudio.play("https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/167999916/stream?client_id=123456576789");

  }
});
```

template

```
<div class="container" id="player">

  <button class='btn btn-primary' ng-click='ngAudio.paused ? ngAudio.play() : ngAudio.pause()'>{{ngAudio.paused ? "Play" : "Pause" }}</button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is a component, have you tried just...

```
this.ngAudio = ngAudio;
```

?

No, actually, according to docs, you want to set it to the result of `load` or `play`, like:

```
this.audio = ngAudio.play("https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/167999916/stream?client_id=123456576789");
```

See the "Angular Audio Example" piece in the docs at http://danielstern.github.io/ngAudio/#/docs
(At the very bottom of the page)

Comment: Thanks! Just put this in and still no look with the bindings in the template. It's showing as undefined within the HTML of the template.

Comment: The ngAudio here is the service not the directive, and what you are trying to access is actually the result of the `play` call, so, I think you should assign to that. I updated the answer, have a look at the added link too.

Comment: Thank you! You were right, I was referring to the service as opposed to an instance of it. Have a great day :)